# Inherited parent class function not displaying correct output

Tags: c++, inheritance, istream

Fellow programmers, I have a problem which can be described as below :
My parent class error messages work successfully but when i call the parent function on my child class Perishable , then it doesn't input any error messages (including the new error messages added by itself). 
The NonPerishable class also inherits an Error class who controls error messages(also has other child classes who have all the items variables and data defined).

```
  class NonPerishable : public Error {

        public:
            Error m_err;
        public:
void clear();
            bool isClear()const;
            bool ok()const;
            void error(const char* message);
            virtual char signature()const;
        public:
            std::fstream& save(std::fstream& file)const;
            std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
            std::ostream& write(std::ostream& ostr, bool linear)const;
            std::istream& read(std::istream& is);
        };
```

////////////////////////////////////

```
class Perishable : public NonPerishable {

    private:
        Date m_expiry;
    protected:
        char signature()const;
    public:
        Perishable();
        std::fstream& save(std::fstream& file)const;
        std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
        std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const;
        std::istream& read(std::istream& istr);
    };
    class Perishable : public NonPerishable {

    private:
        Date m_expiry;
    protected:
        char signature()const;

public:
    Perishable();
    std::fstream& save(std::fstream& file)const;
    std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const;
    std::istream& read(std::istream& istr);
};
```

Parent class read() function :

```
std::istream & ict::NonPerishable::read(std::istream & is)
{
    char t_sku[MAX_SKU_LEN + 1];
    char t_name[256];

    double t_price;
    char t_taxed[2];
    int t_quantity;

    cout << "Item Entry: " << endl;
    cout << "Sku: ";
    is >> t_sku;
    if (is.fail()) {
        error("Invalid Sku Entry");
        goto label;
    }
    else {
        sku(t_sku);
    }
    //is.ignore(2000, '\n');
    cout << "Name: " << endl;
    is >> t_name;
    name(t_name);
    cout << "Price: ";
    is >> t_price;
    if (is.fail()) {

        error("Invalid Price Entry");
        goto label;
    }
    else {
        price(t_price);
    }
    is.ignore(2000, '\n');
    cout << "Taxed: ";
    is.getline(t_taxed, 2);
    if (is.fail() || (t_taxed[0] != 'y' && t_taxed[0] != 'n')) {
        error("Invalid Taxed Entry, (y)es or (n)o");
        is.setstate(ios::failbit);
        goto label;
    }
    else {
        if (t_taxed[0] == 'y') {
            taxed(true);
        }
        if (t_taxed[0] == 'n') {
            taxed(false);
        }
    }
    cout << "Quantity: ";
    is >> t_quantity;
    if (is.fail()) {
        error("Invalid Quantity Entry");
        goto label;
    }
    else {
        quantity(t_quantity);
    }

label:
    return is;
}
```

Perishable Child class read() function:

```
std::istream & ict::Perishable::read(std::istream & istr)
{
    cout << "Perishable ";
    NonPerishable::read(istr);
    if (!istr.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Expiry date (YYYY/MM/DD): ";
    }
    istr >> m_expiry;
    if (m_expiry.bad() == true) {

        if (m_expiry.errCode() == CIN_FAILED) {
            error("Invalid Date Entry");
        }
        istr.clear();
        if (m_expiry.errCode() == YEAR_ERROR) {
            error("Invalid Year in Date Entry");
        }
        istr.clear();
        if (m_expiry.errCode() == MON_ERROR) {
            error("Invalid Month in Date Entry");
        }
        istr.clear();
        if (m_expiry.errCode() == DAY_ERROR) {
            error("Invalid Day in Date Entry");
        }
        istr.clear();
    }
    istr.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    istr.ignore();
    return istr;
}
```

Test output working for Non Perishable class :

Child class Perishable tester.cpp

```
#include "Perishable.h"
using namespace ict;
using namespace std;
#define FileName "perish.txt"
void piv(const char* upc, const char* name, const char* price = "",
  const char* taxed = "", const char* qty = "", const char* date = ""){
  cout
    << "Enter the following: " << endl
    << "Sku: " << upc << endl
    << "Name:" << endl << name << endl;
  if (price[0]) cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
  if (taxed[0]) cout << "Taxed: " << taxed << endl;
  if (qty[0]) cout << "Quantity: " << qty << endl;
  if (date[0]) cout << "Expiry date: " << date << endl;
  cout << endl;
}
void dumpFile(const char* fname){
  ifstream f(fname);
  char ch;
  while (!f.get(ch).fail()){
    cout.put(ch);
  }
  f.clear();
  f.close();
}
void _pause(){
  cout << "****press enter to continue...";
  cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
}

int main(){
  Perishable pr;
  bool ok = true;
  int i;
  cout << "--Perishable Error Handling test:" << endl;
  cout << "Each test must display the error message related to the test." << endl << endl;
  cout << "----Price validation test:" << endl;
  piv("abc", "abc", "abc");
  cin >> pr;
  if (cin.fail()){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
    cout << "Error: " << pr << endl;
  }
  else{
    ok = false;
    cout << "Price validation failed" << endl;
  }
  _pause();
  if (ok){
    cout << "----Taxed validation test:" << endl;
    piv("abc", "abc", "10", "abc");
    cin >> pr;
    if (cin.fail()){
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
      cout << "Error: " << pr << endl;
    }
    else{
      ok = false;
      cout << "Taxed validaton failed" << endl;
    }
  }
  _pause();
  if (ok){
    cout << "----Quantity validation test:" << endl;
    piv("abc", "abc", "10", "y", "abc");
    cin >> pr;
    if (cin.fail()){
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
      cout << "Error: " << pr << endl;
    }
    else{
      ok = false;
      cout << "Quantity validaton failed" << endl;
    }
  }
```

Output (not showing error messages) :
[image]

I have been trying to fix this issue for four hour straight , without any result . Any help would be appreciated ! Tell me if u need me to show more of my class code. Thanks.

EDIT: Also added Error.h class header for more clarity.

```
 class Error {
            char* m_message;
        public:
            // constructors
            Error();
            Error(const char* errorMessage);
            // destructor
            virtual ~Error();
            // operator= for c-style strings
            void operator=(const char* errorMessage);
            // method
            void message(const char* value){
                delete[] m_message;
                m_message = new char[strlen(value) + 1];
                strcpy(m_message, value);
            }
    };
```

Comment: Why explicitly use fstreams? Why use char pointers? Why not use std::string? Why are people so determined to make life so difficult for themselves?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am not allowed to use std::string in this phase of my project , so I am forced to use those . I use fstream because I am also writing in a file , which works correctly and its not part of my error message validation test.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use std::string" Something concerted has to be done to put an end to this nonsense.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Once again , I know this is a non-efficient way of working with char arrays , but that is not the source of the issue here , the issue is with the error(const char* message) function inherited from the parent class. Thanks

Comment: `Error` both as base class and as a class member seems very suspicious to me. As for "trying to fix this for hours" - you don't have a heap corruption, or strange compilation issue, or something weird. Just a nice logic error inside a small piece of a code, and to make things easier you also have a failing test. Use the damn debugger already, trace through your code and see where it doesn't do what you thought it should! It's like 10 minutes of work *if you understand what your code is supposed to do*.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin the code is much longer than that , but I didn't show it on purpose , because its not connected to the problem , I am not very experienced with the debugger but I did test the error message by printing it on screen with cout and it shows the correct output , so I think there is something else deeper going on the code

Comment: Ok... There is obviously some unlisted but very relevant code: `NonPerishable::error(const char*)`,  `?::operator?` (whichever executes in `cout << pr` construct) implementations. Basically it boils down to finding out whether correct error was setup (you said it is), whether your code reads it correctly (no idea here, I kinda think it is not because of the two Error instances)  and if yes then finding out where it was cleared. I really recommend learning how to use debugger; if you are using MSVS it has a powerful yet user-friendly debugger.